# How to filter a table base on json array value in another table

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I have 2 tables, one for users and one for posts:

```sql
create database db;

create table if not exists db.users
(
    uid       char(10) primary key,
    username  char(10),
    following json,
    blocked   json
);

insert into db.users (uid, username, following, blocked)
VALUES ('uid_0', 'user_0', '["uid_1", "uid_2"]', '["uid_3"]');

insert into db.users (uid, username, following, blocked)
VALUES ('uid_1', 'user_1', '["uid_0", "uid_2", "user_3"]', '[]');

insert into db.users (uid, username, following, blocked)
VALUES ('uid_2', 'user_2', '["uid_0"]', '[]');

insert into db.users (uid, username, following, blocked)
VALUES ('uid_3', 'user_3', '["uid_1"]', '[]');

create table if not exists db.posts
(
    id    char(10) primary key,
    owner char(10),
    text  char(100)
);

insert into db.posts (id, owner, text)
VALUES ('post_0', 'uid_0', 'text_0');

insert into db.posts (id, owner, text)
VALUES ('post_1', 'uid_1', 'text_1');

insert into db.posts (id, owner, text)
VALUES ('post_2', 'uid_2', 'text_2');

insert into db.posts (id, owner, text)
VALUES ('post_3', 'uid_3', 'text_3');
```

What I want to do is to query the posts of one user based on the following list and on the blocked list.

The far I could go is to transform the following list into a table using a sentinel table that just has numbers from 0 to 1000.

```sql
SET @following = (select following
                  from firestore_mirror.users
                  where uid = 'userId');

SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@following, CONCAT('$[', helper._row, ']')) as uid
FROM (SELECT @following AS helper) AS A
         INNER JOIN firestore_mirror.t_list_row AS helper
                    ON helper._row < JSON_LENGTH(@following);
```

this gives me this

```
"value_0"
"value_1"
"value_2"
"value_3"
"value_4"
```

But when I try this I just get an empty result

```sql
SET @following = (select following
                  from firestore_mirror.users
                  where uid = 'userId');

select *
from firestore_mirror.posts
where owner in (SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@following, CONCAT('$[', helper._row, ']')) as uid
                FROM (SELECT @following AS helper) AS A
                         INNER JOIN firestore_mirror.t_list_row AS helper
                                    ON helper._row < JSON_LENGTH(@following));
```

I am using Cloud SQL with MySql 8.0.

In my head (:))) the result that I am expecting would be

```sql
select *
from db.posts
where owner in (select following from db.users where uid = 'uid_0')
  and owner not in (select blocked from db.users where uid = 'uid_0');
```

```
id, owner, text
"post_1", "uid_1", "text_1"
"post_2", "uid_2", "text_2"
```

Comment: Provide sample data (3-5 rows) as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO and desired output for this data with explanations.

Comment: *`.. where owner in .. and owner not in ..`* Does it is possible that the same `uid` is included in both `following` and `blocked`?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT posts.*
FROM users u1
JOIN users u2 ON JSON_SEARCH(u1.following, 'one', u2.uid)
--           AND JSON_SEARCH(u1.blocked, 'one', u2.uid) IS NULL
JOIN posts ON u2.username = posts.owner
WHERE u1.uid = @uid
```

If the same `uid` may be present in both `following` and `blocked` columns, and the posts owned by such user must not be returned, then uncomment.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2399bc226e47b3b93e3e5016908677ee